# my android app has an intent service which does run but is not showing in list of services

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

I have an intent service in my application. When my application starts up it successfully runs the service class and it works nicely (storing data obtained from bluetooth in a `sqlite` database). The intent service is just for my app and will not be used by other apps.

However, when the application has been inactive for a long while, the service sometimes stops running. I want my service to carry on running reliably--that's why I created a service. I also want the service to start up by itself when the phone boots up (which it does not do).

When I go to `settings -> applications -> running services` my service is not listed there.

Here is the relevant part of my manifest file:

```
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyHxMService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
        <action
        android:name="org.xxxxx.MyHxMService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="MyStartupIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
        <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Here is my intent service class declaration:

```
public class MyHxMService extends IntentService {
```

Here is my **MyStartupIntentReceiver**:

```
package com.NewApp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyStartupIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("org.xxxxx.MyHxMService");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
}
```

Comment: Aren't intent services supposed to respond to an intent then finish execution once they run out of stuff do to?

Comment: @Martin Kellerman have you declared `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Hi Vmironov, I have now added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` to my manifest, but it still doesn;t start up by itself on boot. Does it make a difference that my app is installed on the sdcard?

Answer (score 1):

Start  `MyHxMService` Service as

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,org.xxxxx.MyHxMService.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Comment: works!! Thanks. Wonder why your answer is not accepted..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Termination of service : `IntentService` is designed to be like an `AsyncTask`, it stops as soon as its work is done. If you need other behavior, consider extending the `Service` class itself. Also, returning `START_STICKY` from  `onStartCommand()` in `Service` class tells android to keep it alive unless explicitly stopped.
2. Start Up at Boot: You have already setup the BOOT_COMPLETED IntentReciever, just create the Intent with proper Context and Component Class as shown in other answer.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that an intent service is not supposed to run indefinitely. I was completely unaware of that. I have changed my service from an IntentService to a Service and I start it in a new thread so it doesn't block my app. Now it is listed in the running services.